# Extra gap between the columns in colored tables

Tags: tables, color, booktabs, colortbl

Tables again. I want to color several rows in the table and use colortbl package. Everything works fine. Now I want to add extra gap between the first and the second column to make the table more legible. I do it in the way of adding `@{\hspace{20pt}}` in the table preamble. Works fine and adds what I want. BUT! It also adds that gap in the color stripe of the table.

**How to add the gap but still have the color row in one piece?**

*(the actual color was changed to make it more visual)*

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{euler, beton}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
%============================================================
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{\hspace{20pt}}*{3}{l@{\enspace}l}l@{\enspace}l@{\enspace}lp{1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}
\toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{\#}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{\small Results}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Scores}& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{1.2cm}{All Diff\textsuperscript{nt}?}}&\multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{1.5cm}{Draws}}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{1}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{2}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{3}&\multirow{2}{*}{A}&\multirow{2}{*}{B}&\multirow{2}{*}{C}\\ 
\cmidrule(r){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
&A&B&B&C&C&A\\
\midrule
1  &    0  &    2  &    0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & No &    - \\
2  &    0  &    2  &    0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & Yes &   1 \\
3  &    0  &    2  &    1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 1 & Yes &   1 \\
4  &    1  &    1  &    0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & Yes &   1 \\
5  &    0  &    2  &    0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 & Yes &   0 \\
6  &    0  &    2  &    2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 0 & Yes &   0 \\
7  &    2  &    0  &    0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 2 & Yes &   0 \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
8  &    0  &    2  &    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & Yes &   2 \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
9  &    1  &    1  &    0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 3 & Yes &   2 \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
10 &    1  &    1  &    1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1 & Yes &   2 \\
11 &    0  &    2  &    2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 2 & Yes &   0 \\
12 &    2  &    0  &    2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & Yes &   0 \\
13 &    2  &    0  &    0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 4 & Yes &   0 \\
14 &    1  &    1  &    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & No &- \\
15 &    2  &    0  &    2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & No &- \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
16 &    2  &    0  &    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 2 & Yes &   2 \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
17 &    1  &    1  &    2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & Yes &   2 \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
18 &    1  &    1  &    1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & Yes &   2 \\
19 &    1  &    1  &    2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 2 & Yes &   1 \\
20 &    2  &    0  &    1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 3 & Yes &   1 \\
21 &    2  &    0  &    2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 1 & Yes &   1 \\
22 &    0  &    2  &    1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 3 & No &1 \\
23 &    0  &    2  &    2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1 & No &1 \\
24 &    1  &    1  &    0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 4 & No &1 \\
25 &    1  &    1  &    2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 0 & No &1 \\
26 &    2  &    0  &    0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 3 & No &1 \\
27 &    2  &    0  &    1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 1 & No &1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @John Kormylo, I tried this. The first column becomes wider (as expected), but the gap is still there.

Comment: I did. Same thing. I think @{} is about trimming the very left side of the table, It looks like p{} is about the width only. Although, my question is about filling the gap. I thought colortbl is supposed to take care of it

Comment: If I remove it the color stripe is obviously in one piece - colortbl works fine. But I think I need that gap because otherwise the table is not that legible (in my opinion).

Comment: Your LightCyan colour  looks a bit weird…

Comment: @Bernard, maybe. I changed it into red to make it more visual - this is not the most important part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add an empty column between the first and the second column – not forgetting to shift the \cmidrules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{euler, beton}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
%============================================================
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\begin{document}
%\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{\hspace{20pt}}*{3}{l@{\enspace}l}l@{\enspace}l@{\enspace}lp{1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}rc*{3}{l@{\enspace}l}l@{\enspace}l@{\enspace}lp{1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}
\toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{\#}& & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\small Results}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Scores}& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{1.2cm}{All Diff\textsuperscript{nt}?}}&\multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{1.5cm}{Draws}}\\
\cmidrule(r){3-8}
\cmidrule(lr){9-11}
 & &\multicolumn{2}{c}{1}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{2}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{3}&\multirow{2}{*}{A}&\multirow{2}{*}{B}&\multirow{2}{*}{C}\\
\cmidrule(r){3-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
\cmidrule(lr){7-8}
& & A&B&B&C&C&A\\
\midrule
1 & & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & No & - \\
2 & & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & Yes & 1 \\
3 & & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 1 & Yes & 1 \\
4 & & 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & Yes & 1 \\
5 & & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 & Yes & 0 \\
6 & & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 0 & Yes & 0 \\
7 & & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 2 & Yes & 0 \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
8 & & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & Yes & 2 \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
9 & & 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 3 & Yes & 2 \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
10 & & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1 & Yes & 2 \\
11 & & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 2 & Yes & 0 \\
12 & & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & Yes & 0 \\
13 & & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 4 & Yes & 0 \\
14 & & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & No &- \\
15 & & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & No &- \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
16 & & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 2 & Yes & 2 \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
17 & & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & Yes & 2 \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
18 & & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & Yes & 2 \\
19 & & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 2 & Yes & 1 \\
20 & & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 3 & Yes & 1 \\
21 & & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 1 & Yes & 1 \\
22 & & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 3 & No &1 \\
23 & & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1 & No &1 \\
24 & & 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 4 & No &1 \\
25 & & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 0 & No &1 \\
26 & & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 3 & No &1 \\
27 & & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 1 & No &1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the spaces using <{...} instead of @{...}.

I believe there is an automatic overlap which is big enough for the `\enspace` but not the 20pt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{euler, beton}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
%============================================================
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}r<{\hspace{20pt}}@{}*3{l<{\enspace}@{}l}l<{\enspace}@{}l<{\enspace}@{}lp{1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}
\toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{\#}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{\small Results}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Scores}& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{1.2cm}{All Diff\textsuperscript{nt}?}}&\multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{1.5cm}{Draws}}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{1}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{2}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{3}&\multirow{2}{*}{A}&\multirow{2}{*}{B}&\multirow{2}{*}{C}\\ 
\cmidrule(r){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
&A&B&B&C&C&A\\
\midrule
1  &    0  &    2  &    0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & No &    - \\
2  &    0  &    2  &    0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & Yes &   1 \\
3  &    0  &    2  &    1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 1 & Yes &   1 \\
4  &    1  &    1  &    0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & Yes &   1 \\
5  &    0  &    2  &    0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 & Yes &   0 \\
6  &    0  &    2  &    2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 0 & Yes &   0 \\
7  &    2  &    0  &    0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 2 & Yes &   0 \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
8  &    0  &    2  &    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & Yes &   2 \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
9  &    1  &    1  &    0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 3 & Yes &   2 \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
10 &    1  &    1  &    1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1 & Yes &   2 \\
11 &    0  &    2  &    2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 2 & Yes &   0 \\
12 &    2  &    0  &    2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & Yes &   0 \\
13 &    2  &    0  &    0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 4 & Yes &   0 \\
14 &    1  &    1  &    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & No &- \\
15 &    2  &    0  &    2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & No &- \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
16 &    2  &    0  &    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 2 & Yes &   2 \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
17 &    1  &    1  &    2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & Yes &   2 \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
18 &    1  &    1  &    1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & Yes &   2 \\
19 &    1  &    1  &    2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 2 & Yes &   1 \\
20 &    2  &    0  &    1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 3 & Yes &   1 \\
21 &    2  &    0  &    2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 1 & Yes &   1 \\
22 &    0  &    2  &    1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 3 & No &1 \\
23 &    0  &    2  &    2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1 & No &1 \\
24 &    1  &    1  &    0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 4 & No &1 \\
25 &    1  &    1  &    2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 0 & No &1 \\
26 &    2  &    0  &    0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 3 & No &1 \\
27 &    2  &    0  &    1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 1 & No &1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```